# How to use the range version of `transform()` with two ranges?

Tags: c++, c++20

The header `<algorithm>` contains a version of `std::transform()` taking a two input sequences, an output sequence, and a binary function as parameters, e.g.:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v0{1, 2, 3};
    std::vector<int> v1{4, 5, 6};
    std::vector<int> result;
    std::transform(v0.begin(), v0.end(), v1.begin(), std::back_inserter(result),
                   [](auto a, auto b){ return a + b; });
    std::copy(result.begin(), result.end(),
              std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

C++20 introduced *range algorithms* which does include `std::ranges::views::transform(R, F)` and its implementation `std::ranges::views::transform_view`. I can see how to use this `transform()` with one range, e.g.:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

int main()
{   
    std::vector<int> v0{1, 2, 3}; 
    for (auto x: std::ranges::views::transform(v0, [](auto a){ return a + 3; })) {
        std::cout << x << ' ';
    }   
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

However, there is no version supporting more than one range. So, the question becomes: How to use the range version of `transform()` with two (or more) ranges? On objective of this approach is to benefit from the lazy evaluation of views and avoid the creation of an intermediate sequence (`result` in the non-ranges version above). A potential use could look like this (putting the function argument in front to make it easier for a potential solution allowing even more than two ranges):

```
for (auto v: envisioned::transform([](auto a, auto b){ return a + b; }, v0, v1) {
    std::cout << v << ' ';
}
std::cout << '\n';
```

Comment: I would say zip_view first, but not C++20.

Comment: There is no such function or capability in C++20.

Comment: @Jarod42: yes, ranges-v3 does contain `zip()` but C++20 doesn't. I think it is still the answer but it will take me a moment to punch in `zip()` :)

Comment: Can you show an example usage of the 2 input range version of `transform` that you would like to write?

Comment: @cigien: I would like to replace the non-ranges version by one using ranges, e.g., to avoid creating a temporary range. That could look like so (I have swapped the function argument to the front as that makes things a bit easier to implement for an arbitrary number of ranges): for (auto v: envisioned::transform([](auto a, auto b){ return a + b; }, v0, v1)){ std::cout << v << ' '; }`. Inside `envisioned::transform()` I would envision using `std::ranges::views::transform()`.

Comment: An *arbitrary* number of ranges can't be handled, but you can use 2 input ranges. The specific example you've shown in the comment is implementable with C++20 ranges. If that's sufficient, add that to the question, and I'll post an answer.

Comment: @cigien: I have update my question. I do believe a solution with an arbitrary number of ranges (well, there is probably some technical limitation but the conceptually it could be arbitrary) is actually possible. However, a replacement of the two sequences supported by `std::transform()` would bring things on par with that version of `transform()`.

Comment: I've added an answer that address at least the 2 input version in C++20.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The way you would like to use `transform`, where you take an arbitrary number of input ranges is not possible directly with what's available in `<algorithm>` as of C++20. You can of course write such an algorithm yourself without too much effort.

The example with 2 input ranges can be implemented in C++20 like this:

```
std::ranges::transform(v0, v1,
                       std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "),
                       std::plus{});
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vf4oax), and this is specifically the last overload of `transform` listed [here](https://eel.is/c++draft/alg.transform).

There is unfortunately no way to write the equivalent version like this:

```
for (auto v : std::views::transform(v0, v1, std::plus{})) // no, unfortunately    
  std::cout << v << " ";
```

but the above implementation does the same thing. It certainly satisfies your requirements of not having to store the results separately; they can be printed as they're generated.

Comment: I'm not seeing `std::ranges::transform` which takes two ranges, though. There is (in [range.transform]) `std::ranges::views::transform` but I don't think this algorithm (view factory) takes two ranges. Do you have a reference to version you are using?

Comment: @DietmarKühl  The last overload [here](https://eel.is/c++draft/alg.transform) is the correct one, and it does [work](https://godbolt.org/z/vf4oax). Would you like me to add the demo and/or reference to the answer?

Comment: I just tried it out with `g++` and it, indeed, works. It may be an extension in `libstdc++`.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Ah, ok then. I added the demo and the reference to the answer anyway :)

Comment: You are right: these versions are, indeed, defined. ... with a somewhat interesting way of defining them and in the `<algorithm>` header rather than the `<ranges>` header. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

What you're looking for is the algorithm that range-v3 calls `zip_with` and what we are proposing in [P2214](https://wg21.link/p2214) to add to C++23 under the name `zip_transform`. There is no such algorithm in C++20.

Until then, the range-v3 version is exactly your use-case:

```cpp
for (auto v : zip_with([](auto a, auto b){ return a + b; }, v0, v1)) {
    std::cout << v << ' ';
}
```

It can handle an arbitrary number of ranges.

Note that there is no piping version here, just as there is not with regular `zip`.

Comment: That's actually interesting: the `zip_with()` transformation is what would build a resulting `std::tuple` if a `tuple`-like elements is desired. However, different ways to combine the sequences are supported, too. Seems that is really a form of `transform()` under a different name: I guess, I prefer `zip_transform` (but let's see what LEWG makes out of that).

Comment: I was just typing my own answer but seeing one from someone who actually wrote P2214 made me instantly delete it. P1035R5 mentions that `zip_view` was removed as per request from the LEWG, but I could not find any information on what that request was based on. Do you have any information on that?

Comment: @DietmarKühl Right. If you just want a tuple, you use `zip`. But if you want to apply a function, it's just a more direct way of doing that -- there's no intermediate tuple that gets built up or anything, just `std::invoke(f, *it...)`

Comment: @mrks Read the two sections in the paper about making `tuple` `readable` and `writable`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer blow is how I envisioned to answer the question and I think it still contains some interesting bits on how to actually implement a view. It turns out that [P2214](https://wg21.link/p2214) mentioned in [@Barry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65450947/1120273) has an interesting view (`zip_transform`) which does an intermediate step of the solution posted below but actually fully covers the functionality needed to do a multi-range `transform`!

It seems there are essentially two ingredients to using `std::ranges::views::transform()` with multiple ranges:

1. Some way to *zip* the objects at the corresponding positions of the ranges into a `std::tuple`, probably retaining the value category of the respective values.
2. Instead of using an n-ary function to take the elements of the range as parameters the function would rather use a `std::tuple` and possibly use that to call a corresponding n-ary function.

Using this idea would allow creating a version of `transform()` dealing with an arbitrary number of ranges, although it is easier to take the function object first rather than extract the last element of a parameter pack:

```
auto transform(auto&& fun, auto&&... ranges)
{
    return std::ranges::views::transform(zip(std::forward<decltype(ranges)>(ranges)...),
                                         [fun = std::forward<decltype(fun)>(fun)]
                                         (auto&& t){ return std::apply(fun, std::forward<decltype(t)>(t)); });
}
```

The `zip` view used by this implementation can be implemented in terms of `std::tuple`:

```
template <typename... Range>
struct zip_view
    : std::ranges::view_base
{
    template <typename V>
    struct rvalue_view
    {
        std::shared_ptr<std::decay_t<V>> view;
        rvalue_view() = default;
        rvalue_view(V v): view(new std::decay_t<V>(std::move(v))) {}
        auto begin() const { return this->view->begin(); }
        auto end() const { return this->view->end(); }
    };
    template <typename T>
    using element_t = std::conditional_t<
        std::is_rvalue_reference_v<T>,
        rvalue_view<T>,
        T
        >;
    using storage_t = std::tuple<element_t<Range>...>;
    using value_type = std::tuple<std::ranges::range_reference_t<std::remove_reference_t<Range>>...>;
    using reference = value_type;
    using difference_type = std::common_type_t<std::ranges::range_difference_t<Range>...>;
    storage_t ranges;
    
    template <typename> struct base;
    template <std::size_t... I>
    struct base<std::integer_sequence<std::size_t, I...>>
    {
        using value_type = zip_view::value_type;
        using reference = zip_view::value_type;
        using pointer = value_type*;
        using difference_type = std::common_type_t<std::ranges::range_difference_t<Range>...>;
        using iterator_category = std::common_type_t<std::random_access_iterator_tag,
                                                     typename std::iterator_traits<std::ranges::iterator_t<Range>>::iterator_category...>;

        using iterators_t = std::tuple<std::ranges::iterator_t<Range>...>;
        iterators_t iters;

        reference operator*() const { return {*std::get<I>(iters)...}; }
        reference operator[](difference_type n) const { return {std::get<I>(iters)[n]...}; }
        void increment() { (++std::get<I>(iters), ...); }
        void decrement() { (--std::get<I>(iters), ...); }
        bool equals(base const& other) const {
            return ((std::get<I>(iters) == std::get<I>(other.iters)) || ...);
        }
        void advance(difference_type n){ ((std::get<I>(iters) += n), ...); }
        
        base(): iters() {}
        base(const storage_t& s, auto f): iters(f(std::get<I>(s))...) {}
    };

    struct iterator
        : base<std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Range)>>
    {
        using base<std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Range)>>::base;
        iterator& operator++() { this->increment(); return *this; }
        iterator  operator++(int) { auto rc(*this); operator++(); return rc; }
        iterator& operator--() { this->decrement(); return *this; }
        iterator  operator--(int) { auto rc(*this); operator--(); return rc; }
        iterator& operator+= (difference_type n) { this->advance(n); return *this; }
        iterator& operator-= (difference_type n) { this->advance(-n); return *this; }
        bool      operator== (iterator const& other) const { return this->equals(other); }
        auto      operator<=> (iterator const& other) const {
            return std::get<0>(this->iters) <=> std::get<0>(other.iters);
        }
        friend iterator operator+ (iterator it, difference_type n) { return it += n; }
        friend iterator operator+ (difference_type n, iterator it) { return it += n; }
        friend iterator operator- (iterator it, difference_type n) { return it -= n; }
        friend difference_type operator- (iterator it0, iterator it1) {
            return std::get<0>(it0.iters) - std::get<0>(it1.iters);
        }
    };

    zip_view(): ranges() {}
    template <typename... R>
    zip_view(R&&... ranges): ranges(std::forward<R>(ranges)...) {}

    iterator begin() const { return iterator(ranges, [](auto& r){ return std::ranges::begin(r); }); }
    iterator end() const { return iterator(ranges, [](auto& r){ return std::ranges::end(r); }); }
};

auto zip(auto&&... ranges)
    -> zip_view<decltype(ranges)...>
{
    return {std::forward<decltype(ranges)>(ranges)...};
}
```

This implementation makes some decisions about the `value_type` and the `reference` type and how to keep track of the different ranges. Other choices may be more reasonable ([P2214](http://wg21.link/p2214) makes slightly different, probably better, choices). The only tricky bit in this implementation is operating on the `std::tuple`s which requires a parameter pack containing indices or a suitable set of algorithms on `std::tuple`s.

With all of that in place a multi-range `transform` can be used nicely, e.g.:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <memory>
#include <ranges>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
    
// zip_view, zip, and transform as above

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v0{1, 2, 3};
    std::vector<int> v1{4, 5, 6};
    std::vector<int> v2{7, 8, 9};
    for (auto x: transform([](auto a, auto b, auto c){ return a + b + c; }, v0, v1, v2)) {
        std::cout << x << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: There's a few issues with this implementation of `zip`. For some inputs, it fails to meet the semantics of `view` (`zip(std::move(v0))` isn't O(1) copyable). For others it doesn't work (like `zip(as_const(v0))` because the reference type is wrong). Also, `zip` could be random access.

Comment: @Barry: Thanks for pointing out the issues! I think I have addressed those you mentioned. The code certainly isn't thoroughly tested and there are probably other issues.