# Fold expressions in algorithms for std::tuple access

Tags: c++, c++20

When dealing with generic structures to hold some combination of other entities I often end up using `std::tuple` with the need to apply operations to individual elements of the `std::tuple`. For example, when I implemented a ["zip iterator"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65451686/1120273) the underlying ranges and iterators were stored in a `std::tuple`. While it is reasonably straight forward to hack up custom function or class templates using an `std::index_sequence<std::tuple_size<Tuple>>` to get the relevant elements, it seems using algorithms operating on `std::tuple`s or `std::tuple`-like structures (e.g., `std::array` or `std::pair`) could improve the code.

Some operations are fairly straight forward to implement. For example, `tuple_for_each()` could either dispatch to a recursive implementation or an implementation based on `std::index_sequence` to apply the elements:

```
template <typename Tuple, typename Fun>
void tuple_for_each(Tuple&& tuple, Fun fun)
{
    auto const impl = [&tuple, fun]<std::size_t...I>(std::index_sequence<I...>){
        (fun(std::get<I>(tuple)), ...);
    };
    impl(std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<std::decay_t<Tuple>>>());
}
```

When the operation isn't really element-wise as in `for_each` or `transform` (for the latter producing the return type is a bit more interesting) but the result of a function applied to the elements is combined to produce a result a generic algorithm doesn't seem to work as simple. The algorithm would be somewhat like `accumulate` or `inner_product`. These can be written quite easy in a custom setting, e.g.,

```
template <typename... T>
struct some_struct {
    std::tuple<T...> tuple;

    template <typename Tuple, std::size_t... I>
    static bool equals(Tuple&& t0, Tuple&& t1, std::index_sequence<I...>) {
        return ((std::get<I>(t0) == std::get<I>(t1)) && ...);
    }
    bool operator== (some_struct const& other) const {
        return equals(this->tuple, other.tuple, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(T)>());
    }
};
```

It would be nice if this `operator==()` could just delegate to a suitable `tuple` algorithm:

```
bool operator== (some_struct const& other) const  {
    return tuple_inner_product(this->tuple, other.tuple, true, std::equal_to<>(), std::logical_and<>());
}
```

There doesn't seem to be a way to implement `tuple_inner_product` with a fold expression other than creating special versions based on the type of the last argument. I know how to implement a recursive version but I don't think that version would short-circuit the evaluation if the combining operation is one of the logical operands (the function arguments always need to be determined before the function can be called):

```
template <typename T0, typename T1, typename Init, typename Transform, typename Combine>
auto tuple_inner_product(T0&& t0, T1&& t1, Init init, Transform transform, Combine combine) {
    auto const recurse = [&t0, &t1, transform, combine]<std::size_t I>(
                               std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>,
                               auto const& r, auto init) {
        if constexpr (I == std::min(std::tuple_size_v<std::decay_t<T0>>,
                                    std::tuple_size_v<std::decay_t<T1>>)) {
            return init;
        }
        else {
            return combine(transform(std::get<I>(t0), std::get<I>(t1)),
                           r(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I+1>(), r, init));
        }
    };
    return recurse(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0u>(), recurse, init);
}
```

Thus, the question becomes whether there is a way to implement this algorithm using fold expressions?

Comment: Have you seen std::apply? Both of your examples look easy to write with it. (Not able to actually write and test it right now.)

Comment: You want [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27582862/2069064) basically.

Comment: @HTNW: I think `std::apply()` is sort of the other way around: it calls a function expanding the `std::tuple` elements to become the function arguments. I want to, well, _apply_ a function to each of the elements. For example, if the `std::tuple` contains iterators for different sequences something like `tuple_for_each(tuple, [](auto& it){ ++it; })` becoming `++std::get<0>(tuple), ++std::get<1>(tuple), ...`.

Comment: @Barry: "fold expression with arbitrary callable": yes, mostly that's it. Thanks! I guess, the moment I hide the logic operator into a function object I loose the short circuit property so maybe it is an unreasonable expectation to hope to get it back (it could be recovered for known types like `std::logical_and<>()`, though, by having a special implementation for these).

Comment: Follow up of HTNW comment: `std::apply([](auto&... its){(++its, ...);}, tuple);`.

Comment: @Jarod42: thanks for clarifying! I didn't see this approach but that, indeed, works for my `for_each` and probably also for `transform`.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Here we go:
`void tuple_for_each(auto &&t, auto f) { apply([&](auto&&... xs) { (f(forward<decltype(xs)>(xs)), ...); }, forward<decltype(t)>(t)); } auto tuple_transform(auto &&t, auto f) { return apply([&](auto&&... xs) { return make_tuple(f(std::forward<decltype(xs)>(xs))...); }, std::forward<decltype(t)>(t)); } bool tuple_eq(auto &&l, auto &&r) { return apply([&](auto&&... ls) { return apply([&](auto&&... rs) { return ((std::forward<decltype(ls)>(ls) == std::forward<decltype(rs)>(rs)) && ...); }, forward<decltype(r)>(r)); }, forward<decltype(l)>(l)); }`

Comment: @HTNW: thanks! Jarod42 also enlightened me to see how to use `std::apply()` to implement these functions! I didn't realize this neat trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start with code that generates a tuple of integral constants.

```
template<TupleLike Tuple>
constexpr auto tuple_indexes(Tuple&&);
```

Which is `std::tuple<std::integral_constant<std::size_t,0>, std::integral_constant<std::size_t,1>, ..., std::integral_constant<std::size_t,N-1>` for an nary tuple.

Now we get:

```
bool operator== (some_struct const& other) const  { 
  return std::apply([&](auto...Is){
    return (true &&... && (std::get<Is>(this->tuple)==std::get<Is>(other.tuple)));
  }, tuple_indexes(this->tuple));
}
```

A vocabulary function I also find useful is

```
template<std::size_t N>
using index_t=std::integral_constant<std::size_t,N>;
template<std::size_t N>
constexpr index_t<N> index={};

template<std::size_t...Is>
auto indexer_for(std::index_sequence<Is...>){
  return [](auto&& f)->decltype(auto){ return f(index<Is>...); };
}
template<std::size_t N>
auto indexer_upto(){
  return indexer_for(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}
```

this can be used many ways.  For example,

```
bool operator== (some_struct const& other) const  { 
  return indexer_upto<sizeof...Ts>()([&](auto...Is){
    return (true &&... && (std::get<Is>(this->tuple)==std::get<Is>(other.tuple)));
  });
}
```

as more efficient and more generic than my tuple of indexes above.

Comment: A function creating an `std::index_sequence` from a `std::tuple` is a good idea (although I think it will require slightly different syntax) to avoid a lot of messing about otherwise - thanks!

Comment: @diet you need a way to expand the index sequence into indexes; apply is a prewritten one, or you can roll your own.  I write `indexer(index_sequence)(lambda)` for it for example.

Comment: Thanks for the update: I also didn't see using `integral_constant` here and that converts into `constexpr` values. That's cool! With that my question is actually answered [unlike with the claimed duplicate].

Comment: @diet another version added.  Tuple of indexes is compile time expensive.